# self __init__ overwrite

Tags: methods, initialization, python-2.7, self, overwrite

I'm having trouble with with an initialization of an object, and methods overwriting data that I don't want overwritten.

I apologize if my terminology is incorrect, as I use multiple coding languages for work and I tend to forget some of the lingo when bouncing back and forth.

Example:

```
class SR(object):
        def __init__(self,arg1):

            ...some code with arg1...

            ...import some stuff into a,b,c,d,e...

            self.A = array([a,b,c,d,e)]

            print self.A

            self.B = self.func1(self.A)

            print self.A
            print self.B

        def func1(self,arg2):

            arg2[:,:] += ...some math...
            arg2[:,:] *= ...more math...

            arg3 = ...total of some stuff in arg2...

            return arg3

        def func2(self,arg4):
            ...use func3...
            ...use func1...
            return arg5

        def func3(self,arg4):
            return arg6

        def func4(self,arg7):
            ...output some stuff...                   

instance = SR(2012)

data = {...numbers...}
X = instance.func2(data)
instance.func4('label1')

data = {...numbers...}
X = instance.func2(data)
instance.func4('label2')

data = {...numbers...}
X = instance.func2(data)
instance.func4('label3')

data = {...numbers...}
X = instance.func2(data)
instance.func4('label4')

data = {...numbers...}
X = instance.func2(data)
instance.func4('label5')
```

Prints:

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
[a,not_b,not_c,d,not_e]
[sum-of-a-not_b-not_c-d-not_e]
```

Problem:

The second line printed should look like the first line. I want to be able to change the values within self.A, but I don't want to change them permanently. I thought that func1 would only be receiving a reference or pointer to self.A, but it seems to be over-writing self.A.

How do I fix this?

Keep in mind, I need to use func1 to permanently change data within each instance, but not in self.A.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change self.A, then when you call func1 you should pass:

```
self.func1(list(self.A))
```

Comment: What if my list does not have integer indices? They're tuples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `func1` method modifies its argument in place:

```
    def func1(self,arg2):
        arg2[:,:] += ...some math...
        arg2[:,:] *= ...more math...
```

You probably have a very good reason to do so, but it may have some unintended side-effects, as you've experienced. You have two options, then:

- Modify `func1` so that you don't modify the argument in place. For example:

  ```
  def func1(self, arg2):
      arg2_copy = arg2.copy()
      arg2_copy[:,:] += ....
  ```
- Pass a copy of the argument to `func1`:

  ```
  self.B = self.func1(self.A.copy())
  ```

I used a `.copy` method because I assumed `self.A` was a `ndarray`. If it's not the case, you will have to use the proper trick (like making another list or another dictionary...)